# session value in javascript cannot be set

Tags: javascript, function, session

I am quite new to javascript, I wonder why my session value in javascript wont be set to 1 even I tried. When call this function again, the value of the session will change again.
My javascript code as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function Confirm() {
        alert(<%=Session["Once"]%> != 1);
        var value = document.getElementById("<%=lblTaskNameM.ClientID %>").innerText; 
        if (<%=Session["Once"]%> != 1) {
            if (value == "Task Name :") {
                <%Session["Once"] = "'1'"; %>;
                alert("ASDSAD");
            }
            else {
                <%Session["Once"] = "'1'"; %>;
                alert("按就删除");
            }
        } else {
            '<%Session["Once"] = "'0'"; %>';
            //confirm_value.value = "Yes"; 
        }

    }
</script>
```

I call this function from one image button. first time I click, the alert message throw me true follow by false, click again it suppose give me false and perform `session = 0`. but its give me true and false again.

Comment: You can't mix server and client side code in this fashion.

Comment: @JamesThorpe sorry James, as I said I really new to all these thing. sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is a client-side language.
Session are server-side component.

If you want to update session when user does something on your page, you should create a ajax request to the server.

Or maybe use some client side variables that, for some aspects, are similar to session (they will be forever available in the same page).

Comment: ic, then does javascript has any function similar to session? really appreciate your comment and do let me learn something.

Comment: The quick and dirty way is to use a global variable.
<script>var global = 'hello';</script>
so everywhere you can access and edit this variable.

The cool and clean way is to use sessionStorage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) or localStorage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: but its will reset the value again if the page is reload right?

Comment: with js variables, yes.

Comment: because session can set in one page, and use it in another page. I wish to do something like that. or even haven declare also can simply open a session value.

Comment: take a look to sessionStorage and localStorage on MDN